# PHP - i have problem with download high files

Tags: php, fopen, urldecode

> i Got the problem, my problem with high files. for example i have a 20mb file, its run without problem. them i give it 50mb file. its not load.....

this is my code:

```
$file = './' . $elements[ $oindex ] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $elements[ $otype ] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $elements[ $odate ] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . urldecode( $elements[ $ofile ] );
```

after this i send data fo output function.
the output code:

```
$file = fopen( $filename, 'r' );

$mimetype = mime_content_type( $file );
header( 'Content-Type: ' . $mimetype );

echo fpassthru( $file );
fclose( $file );
```

its work for all formats
but when i use url like this:

```
http://localhost/onwebsite_ir/c/files/ow_free/2018-11/y2mate.com%20-%20retrain_your_mind_new_motivational_video_very_powerful_xp2qjshr-r4_1080p.mp4
```

its not work....

then use this urls :

```
http://localhost/onwebsite_ir/c/files/ow_free/2018-11/NO%20EXCUSES%20-%20Best%20Motivational%20Video.mp4

http://localhost/onwebsite_ir/c/files/ow_portable_ocourses_on/2018-11/01%20-%20Introduction%20to%20the%20Tools%20used%20in%20Mobile%20Repairing%20(English).jpg
```

it will work without any problem

i test any wayse but it not work...

there is problem with video files...

please help me....

Its Downloader Plugin (Check Access Users To Download Files) On Wordpress

---

after this i update my code to:

```
$file_size = filesize( $filename );
$file      = @fopen( $filename, "rb" );
if ( $file ) {
header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fn\"" );
header( "Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" );
header( "Content-Length: $file_size" );
$mimetype = mime_content_type( $file );
header( 'Content-Type: ' . $mimetype );
set_time_limit( 0 );
if ( $t == 'ow_free' ) {
echo fpassthru( $file );

}
fclose( $file );
}
```

after some tests i got underestand my problem with high files then i used this code for download:

```
$file_size = filesize( $filename );
$file      = @fopen( $filename, "rb" );
if ( $file ) {
header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fn\"" );
header( "Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" );
header( "Content-Length: $file_size" );
$mimetype = mime_content_type( $file );
header( 'Content-Type: ' . $mimetype );
set_time_limit( 0 );
fseek( $file, 0 );
while ( ! feof( $file ) ) {
print( @fread( $file, 1024 * 8 ) );
ob_flush();
flush();
if ( connection_status() != 0 ) {
@fclose( $file );
exit;
}
}
```

its works...
but when i played video by this way or downloading, my website goes down...
is the other ways?

Comment: Re: "but it not work...", Is there an error in the log? please be more specific.

Comment: Please add more information on "not work".

Comment: Use **var_dump** to see what is in $elements and the URL that is being constructed

Comment: Please edit your question to include the info text; pictures are not so helpful.

Comment: echo file_get_contents($filename); not work for this.....